# Issues with the lyrics of the UEFA Nations League anthem

Tags: pronunciation, song-lyrics

Recently, a new international football competition was inaugurated, namely the UEFA Nations League. Being this a European-wide cup, the organisers decided to have the anthem in ... Latin! Certainly a better choice than the [Champions League anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League_Anthem), which is in English, French and German.

The new anthem is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxPl3snsFaw) (is actually quite good!). The "official" lyrics are [here](https://www.uefa.com/uefanationsleague/news/newsid=2569365.html). As you can quickly realise, the ordering of the latter does not match the ones in the song. So instead, you can look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKl8bXrz8iE), which syncronises the lyrics with the song.

Now, most of it makes sense. But two things are not clear.

1. The bits that allegedly say "*Hanc in lucem*" (e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKl8bXrz8iE&feature=youtu.be&t=58)). I imagine the singers are not using an Ecclesiastical pronunciation (with which I'm most familiar), so the *c* is not as in Italian ( /tʃ/, when preceding an *e* or an *i* ) but as a "k". Hence the pronunciation? Is that what they are really saying?
2. Around [1:14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKl8bXrz8iE&feature=youtu.be&t=73), it allegedly says "*Lude*", but it just sound so different to it - sounds a bit like *meda* (not a Latin word). Can you recognise that bit of the lyrics?

Comment: @DenisNardin It surely can be. Where did you get that meaning from? What's the verb? I can't find it.

Comment: @luchonacho Sorry, my memory was faulty. Looking for it though I found that *meta* can mean *goal* (http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.11:1474.lewisandshort, meaning II). It survived with that meaning in Italian to denote the name of the try in rugby. Dunno though, so I'll stop speculating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Indeed the singers pronounce *lucem* as /luˈkɛːm/, but their pronunciation is actually inconsistent, e.g. *vince* is [ˈvɪŋ.kɛ] (neither Classical nor Ecclesiastical), and "ae" is pronounced [e] in *praesta* but also [ae̯] in *iunctae*.
2. The description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxPl3snsFaw)  gives the correct lyrics: it is not *lude!* but *certa!* (struggle!, strive!).